# Global Entry: could not schedule interview within next 30 days

Tags: global-entry

Completed the process for Global Entry and received conditional approval email. This email states that I must schedule the interview within 30 days, but I am unable to get an interview time slot within the next 30 days. What should I do? I live in North Carolia, Charlotte Airport is only place for interviews within North & South Carolina and they have no interviews available, you can't even view the site. So I am not even able to Schedule an interview in the 30 day period.

Comment: Do you mean there isn't an interview *available* before 30 days or that there's a fixed 30 day waiting period ?

Comment: @blackbird: He meant the letter states he needs to schedule the interview during the next 30 days. This is commonly (but incorrectly) intrerpreted as that your interview date has to be within next 30 days (it is not, it can be anytime later), and usually no interviews are available at all during this timeframe.This is a common problem with Global Entry nowadays.

Comment: @S. Bachelder: I rewrote your question, please undo if I didn't get it right. Meanwhile, the conditional approval letter clearly states that you must act to schedule the interview within the next 30 days. However the date of the actual interview may be much later; it does not have to be within the next 30 days. See https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1377/~/goes-im-conditionally-approved.-how-do-i-schedule-an-interview

Comment: @GeorgeY. I think the point is that it's not at all clear. One can read "schedule the interview within the next 30 days" as meaning that either the scheduling or the interviewing must happen in that time. The website makes it clear by continuing, "but the actual interview date may be outside that window" -- does the letter also use wording like that?

Comment: A colleague completed her Global Entry application just recently and the first interview appointment she could get was for December 28th, about 5 months delay.  That was in California for what its worth.

Comment: @PeterM true, SFO is particularly bad for that. Also once she gets to the interview, there will be a line too - tell her to expect to spend 2+ hours there at SFO. If she needs it earlier or with less hassle, she can fly to Vegas, the line is much shorter there (although you still need an appointment, and can't just walk in). PS. I just renewed my Global Entry at SFO a few months ago.

Answer (score 12):

You should [schedule an interview](https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/1377/~/goes-im-conditionally-approved.-how-do-i-schedule-an-interview). From the CBP web site (typographical errors theirs):

> You must schedule an appointment within 30-days of receiving you conditional approval, but the actual interview date may be outside that window.  Not scheduling the interview will result in cancelation of the application and no refunds will be granted. Also note that canceling an appointment that has reached the 30-day period from the date of conditional approval can cause your application to be cancelled.  You may reschedule as often as needed outside of the 30 day window.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the rewritten question, it isn't uncommon for really busy airport offices to show no available appointments at all; the office at the airport in Toronto is like that too. All you can do is schedule an appointment somewhere that does have them available before the 30 days is up, then regularly check the office where you want to do the interview looking for cancellations or new dates to open up (you are always free to reschedule an existing appointment). If you never get a date at Charlotte and the appointment you do have is approaching, you'll need to choose whether you want to travel to the appointment you already have or reschedule it for a later date in the hope that some time at your preferred airport will eventually open up.